# How to get a random list item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using discord.py to make a Discord bot that gives you a complement every 24 hours. To test, I set the timer to 1 second. The code I made looked like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

const complements = [
    ...
]

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Logged in!');
    client.user.setActivity("with nice complements.")
    setInterval(console.log,1000,complements[Math.floor(Math.random() * (complements.length - 1))]);
});
```

However, this just returns the same complement every time. Is there any ways it can choose a random complement?

Comment: Is that discord.py or discord.js?

Comment: @Pepe_Worm discord.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters you pass to `setInterval` are evaluated at the time when you pass them to the `setInterval` function not at each execution of it.

So this: `setInterval(console.log,1000,complements[Math.floor(Math.random() * (complements.length - 1))]);`

is equal to:

```
let complement = complements[Math.floor(Math.random() * (complements.length - 1))];
setInterval(console.log,1000, complement);
```

You need to pass a callbnack function to `setInterval` that is executed, and move you random access there.

```
setInterval(() => {
   console.log(complements[Math.floor(Math.random() * (complements.length - 1))])
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use *setInterval* like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  const value = complements[Math.floor(Math.random() * (complements.length - 1))];
  console.log(value);
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pass a fixed argument to `console.log` in each iteration (I'd actually never seen `setInterval` called with more than 2 parameters before and had to look up what it meant :-)), pass a function which, when called, generates a new random value and passes that to `console.log`:

```
 setInterval(() => {
    const complement = complements[Math.floor(Math.random() * (complements.length - 1)) ] ;
    console.log(complement);
 }, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is setInterval. He call the function with the same result. Try it and check console

```js
let x = setInterval(console.log(Math.random()),1000,);

let num = 0;
let y = setInterval(() => {
console.log(num)
num += 1
}
,1000,);
```